# Customizing IdentityDb Context for use of ApplicationRole

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int>
    {
    }
```

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {
    }
```

I wanted the Identity Id to be "int" instead of "Guid" and I was able to do so with the code shown but now that I want to introduce Roles for my endpoints, IdentityDbContext does not allow me to change IdentityRole to "string".

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterAdmin(RegisterModel model)
        {
            var userExists = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
            if (userExists != null)
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Message = "User already exists!" });

            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                Email = model.Email,
                SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                UserName = model.Username
            };
            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Message = "User creation failed! Please check user details and try again." });

            if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.Admin+""))
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(UserRoles.Admin+""));
            if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.User))
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(UserRoles.User));

            if (await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.Admin))
            {
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, UserRoles.Admin);
            }

            return Ok(new Response { Status = "Success", Message = "User created successfully!" });
        }
```

I have this Registration endpoint that I want to Register a user with a specific role.

Comment: I tried to do exactly the same thing, but couldn't get it to work. I followed the docs and thought it would work like the `ApplicationUser` change, but it just wouldn't stick. 
Sorry its not more useful, but it might save you a few days head scratching.

Comment: You defined a new role using `IdentityRole` instead of `ApplicationRole` in the `RegisterAdmin` action.

Comment: The point to ONLY change the Key to int, it prompts to change the ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, and Key all to the same type.